# I am trying to remove the numbers that are in the names of the files, which are in a list:

Tags: python, python-3.5

```
import os
from string import digits


def rename_files():
    #1 - get the file names from the folder
    f=os.listdir("/home/happy/Desktop/testfile")
    print(f)
    #2 - remove numbers from each file name
    x = 0
    while (x<len(f)): 
        b = print(os.rename(f[x], f[x].translate(str.maketrans('','',digits))))
        print(b)
        x=x+1

rename_files()
```

the '`os.listdir`' function returns the following list when i  print it out:

```
['64seattle.jpg', '2chennai.jpg', '55kiev.jpg', '45ithaca.jpg', '54dallas.jpg', '68pune.jpg', '16los angeles.jpg', '46colombo.jpg', '96karachi.jpg', '36sydney.jpg', '47sao paulo.jpg', '93manchester.jpg', '83gainesville.jpg', '35miami.jpg', '29buenos aires.jpg', '72bucharest.jpg', '66san jose.jpg', '69shanghai.jpg', '73delhi.jpg', '47london.jpg', '52new york.jpg', '45austin.jpg', '2hyderabad.jpg', '47singapore.jpg', '61edinbrugh.jpg', '4istanbul.jpg', '29bristol.jpg', '.DS_Store', '17cairo.jpg', '69chicago.jpg', '41seoul.jpg', '88jacksonville.jpg', '22rochester.jpg', '90beijing.jpg', '28houston.jpg', '89berkeley.jpg', '25madrid.jpg', '97oakland.jpg', '9barcelona.jpg', '72bangalore.jpg', '50san diego.jpg', '5bogota.jpg', '74tel aviv.jpg', '48sunnyvale.jpg', '37athens.jpg']
```

I tried a couple different ways, but since I'm a noob and new to this, I'm having a really hard time figuring this out. and ten I try to pass it on to the loop trying to remove the numbers. I'm using python 3.5 btw.

the errors have differentiated from "list object does not have attribute" to "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory" , but i feel like I'm getting closer to solving this problem.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rename` only works with the full file path, otherwise it doesn't find the files. Use `os.path.join()` to pass the full valid path to `rename`, in both arguments.

```
my_dir = "/home/happy/Desktop/testfile"
for f in os.listdir(my_dir):    
    os.rename(os.path.join(my_dir,f), os.path.join(my_dir,f.translate(str.maketrans('','',digits))))
```